# Continuous image of convex sets

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let A be a convex set. Is F(A) convex? 
I know that when F is linear we get such result, does it hold for continuous functions?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is convex **iff** it is connected.